# Reverse Geocoding using Json from Controller Fail

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I'm trying to return all the events onto Google maps but for some reason nothing is returned, I'm making use of ajax as well:
Here is the Controller:

```
public ActionResult LocateEvent()
{
    DataModel1 db = new DataModel1();
    ViewBag.Title = "Locate Event";
    return View(db.Events.ToList());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(string Location)
{
    DataModel1 GE = new DataModel1();
    var result = GE.Events.ToList();
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here is the View where I'm trying to display all the events using their lat and long using ajax:

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

 @*<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false"></script>*@

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    var gmarkers = [];
    var map;

    function initialize() {

        var mapProp = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.875233, 25.4443775), //P.E Lat and Lon
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    for (i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
        gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Search", "Events")', //"../Map/Search"
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        //data: JSON.stringify({ "Location": x }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var table = "<table class='table'>";
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {

                table += "<tr><td>" + value.EventName + "</td></tr>";
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(value.EventLat, value.EventLong);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    icon: "../pinkball.png",
                    map: map
                });

                gmarkers.push(marker);

            });
            table += "</table>";
            $("#myData").html(table);

            if (x == "") {
                for (j = 0; j < gmarkers.length; j++) {
                    gmarkers[j].setMap(null);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You have a method named `LocateEvent()` but `@Url.Action("Locate", "Events")` is calling a method named `Locate()` in `EventController`. The `LocateEvent()` method returns html, but you specify the `data: 'json',` ajax option. Use you browser tools to debug your code and inspect the error messages in the console.

Comment: I've updated the code but the markers don't display

Comment: Does `GE.Events.ToList();` return anything? (you have just initialized a new default object). What does `console.log(value.EventName)` inside the `$.each()` statement output? You need to learn to use you browser tools to debug your scripts

Comment: The only part i'm trying to figure out now is how to pass the data from the controller using the "JSON.stringify" in ajax

Comment: You don't need `JSON.stringify` Remove the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` and use `data: { location: 'x' },`. In the controller, the value of the parameter `string Location` will be `"x"`

Comment: Still not working, do you think it can be something to do with the Api Key?

Comment: What is not working? You need to debug your code. (and why are you making an ajax call when you first load the view anyway - as opposed to just including the collection of data you need in your model?)

Comment: Retrieving the list from the controller is failing. What do you mean "just including the collection of data I need in my model"? Isn't that the reason why I'm making use of the ajax call the get the data from the controller?

Comment: What if I want to display all locations without making use of an search function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem.
The error was that the object passed through the JSON call contained all the properties instead of only passing those fields that I wanted to use.
E.g
I created this class to only pass those field i want to use in the JQuery:

```
    public class ShortEvent
    {
         public string EventName { get; set; }
         public double? EventLat { get; set; }
         public double? EventLong { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I updated the controller like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Search(string Location)
    {
        DataModel1 GE = new DataModel1();          

        var result = GE.Events.Where(x => x.EventName.StartsWith(Location)).Select(e=> new ShortEvent {EventName = e.EventName, EventLat= e.EventLat, EventLong= e.EventLong).ToList();
        try
        {
            var test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result[0]);
        }
        catch ()
        {

        }
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And that's how I managed to solve the problem. Thanks for the help Mr. Muecke, much appreciated.